# RegionPlot error

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions

I'm trying to represent the following table using the command regionplot. The rectangle (0,0), (0.5,0), (0,1),(0.5,1) should be covered, however it is not. Does anyone know what the problem is?
Thank you.

```
tabla = Table[{1/(k + 1) <= b && 1/k > b}, {k, 2, 30, 1}]

RegionPlot[tabla, {b, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> *The rectangle (0,0), (0.5,0), (0,1),(0.5,1) should be covered, however it is not.*

The 29 rectangles in your original `tabla` cover the region `1/31 <=b < 1/2 && 0 <= a <= 1`.

```
ClearAll[tabla]
tabla[n_] := Table[{1/(k + 1) <= b && 1/k > b}, {k, 2, n, 1}];
```

You can specify a large enough value for `PlotPoints` to see all 29 rectangles:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate[tabla[30]], {b, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or plot each rectangle separately and combine then using `Show`:

```
Show[RegionPlot[#[[1]], {b, 0, #[[1, 2, 1]]}, {a, 0, 1}] & /@ tabla[30],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[RegionPlot[#[[1]], {b, 0, #[[1, 2, 1]]}, {a, 0, 1}] & /@ tabla[90], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, combine the conditions using `Or` to get a single rectangle:

```
RegionPlot[Or @@ Join @@ tabla[30], {b, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]